# Display rectangle image as a square cropped image css

Tags: html, css, image

I have a image that is rectangle in shape, like this.

[image]

I want it to displayed like this in one page

[image]

Because I need the rectangle image in another page, it's difficult to have a cropped version and a rectangle version both.

Is there a way using CSS background image, or css in an img tag to display the cropped way of the image as a square.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply using background image and positioning

```
<div style="background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXHMg.jpg'); background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 400px; height: 335px; ">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ycs1s9f9/

Answer (score 1):

See below Sample . I use Background-position to do this.

```css
#myimg
{
  background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXHMg.jpg');
  background-position:-290px -340px;
  width:380px;
  height:320px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="myimg">
  </div>
```